# jQuery animate when <div> loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following code on my site:

```
<!-- Boat weather widget -->
<div id="boat_weather_tab_container">
    <div id="boat_weather_tab">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="widget.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="boat_weather_tab_button">
        <img src="images/blank150.gif">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#boat_weather_tab_button").click(function(){
        // boat_weather_tab_hidden = 1 on page load
        if (boat_weather_tab_hidden) {
            $("#boat_weather_tab").animate({
                marginTop: "-1px"
            }, 500);
            boat_weather_tab_hidden = 0;
        } else {
            $("#boat_weather_tab").animate({
                marginTop: "-254px"
            }, 500);
            boat_weather_tab_hidden = 1;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now the client wants `#boat_weather_tab` to slide back up not just when `#boat_weather_tab_button` is clicked, but when the user clicks anywhere else on the page, which I understand to be the equivalent of when the parent container div `#boat_weather_tab_container` loses focus.

What is the jQuery I would need to accomplish this?

Comment: `.focusout()`: http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hide element when clicked anywhere on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714471/jquery-hide-element-when-clicked-anywhere-on-the-page)

Comment: @sje: `.focusout()` is generally meant for elements that have descendant `<input>` elements. A `<div>` itself can't have focus in the sense that `focusout` requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
$(document).click(function(event)
{
 if(boat_weather_tab_hidden==0 && $("#boat_weather_tab").queue()==0 )
 {
   $("#boat_weather_tab").animate({
                marginTop: "-254px"
            }, 500);
            boat_weather_tab_hidden = 1;

 }
});
```

Not tested, but the idea is the document click will now only hide the boat when it is not currently animating

Comment: This is really close.  When I click `#boat_weather_tab_button`, it slides down correctly, but then slides back up as soon as the first animation ends.

Comment: Actually, this works perfectly, I just had to add `return false;` after each animate in my original function to prevent this animate from firing.

Comment: The `&& $("#boat_weather_tab").queue()==0` you added ensures that the div won't close if the user clicks somewhere else before the animation finishes playing.  I have another problem now: can you think of a way to prevent document clicks within `#boat_weather_tab` from triggering the animation.

Comment: The 'event' parameter should have the coordinates of the mouse, so the method that first comes to mind is to compare the mouse coords against the location+dimensions of the tab to determine if a click was inside the tab or not.  I did a quick search to see if there is a jquery method that already does this, but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [blur event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/). It is essentially the act of losing focus.

```
$("#boat_weather_tab_container").blur(function() {
    //code to run on blur
});
```