# How can I use jQuery to determine if a click event fires within a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm using the following code to animate a block.  In my code, `div_animate()` essentially hides a `<div>` with the specified selector if it is currently visible.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    div_animate("#container");
});
```

I need to determine whether the user clicked on a child of `#container` and if so, `return false;` -- as far as I can tell, the code for this would look something like this:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    if ( /* the event's target has a parent of #container */ ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        div_animate("#container");
    }
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this the same issue as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430277/jquery-animate-when-div-loses-focus) where I gave you [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714471/jquery-hide-element-when-clicked-anywhere-on-the-page)?

Comment: @patrick This is not the same as my previous question, but it is related -- this issue arose when I added the solution from the previous question.

While your link was similar to my original question, I did not find it useful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest thing would be:

```
if ($(event.target).is('#container *, #container')) // edited - thanks @gnarf
  // is a child
else
  // is not a child
```

There are different choices you could make for detecting whether it's a child of the target (or non-target) container; that's just one.  An alternative:

```
if ($(event.target).closest('#container').length)
```

Comment: That wouldn't find `#container` on its own though... Maybe `$(event.target).closest('#container').length` or `.is('#container, #container *')`

Comment: @gnarf ah yes you're right - I had added the "closest" alternative too already but I'll fix the first one.

Comment: @Jazzerus make sure you note the slight edit I made, based on gnarf's comment, and also note Nick's answer(s)

Comment: this will not work properly when `$(anotherselector).trigger(event)` is activated inside the related selector. Example: `$(something).click(function(){ $(anotherselector).trigger(event); });` when this is done `$(document).click(function(e){ if(e.target).is(something) { } });` will always read `anotherselector` as the target of the event, instead of `something`.

Comment: @KeepMove yes, that's true.

Answer (score 9):

You can prevent the action if the click originated on or in `#container`, like this:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    var c = $("#container")[0];
    if (event.target == c || $.contains(c, event.target)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        div_animate("#container");
    }
});
```

The first check is if it came from `#container` itself, the second is if it came from a child, that `#container` [`$.contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/).  A completely alternative, simpler way is to just prevent the bubble up to `document` when clicking on `#container`, like this:

```
$("#container").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  div_animate("#container");
});
```

Comment: Here is my golden opportunity to chastise you for not caching that "#container" lookup, but I bet you'll have edited it by the time I finish typing this comment :-)

Comment: No I meant cached in a closure around the handler function or something, though mostly I was just kidding.

Comment: @Pointy - ah yeah you could, though you're *assuming* it's not changing or moving in that case ;)