# Hide a DIV when it loses focus/blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript that displays a DIV (sets its display css property from 'none' to 'normal'. Is there a way to give it focus as well so that when I click somewhere else on the page, the DIV loses focus and its display property is set to none (basically hiding it). I'm using JavaScript and jQuery

Comment: And what html/jQuery are you using? Can you link to a live demo (perhaps [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/))?

Comment: duplicate, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629774/hide-div-on-blur

Comment: @Sergey, good find. Voted to close as 'exact duplicate.'

Comment: I think e.stopPropagation() is the key as per mentioned in link by Sergey

Comment: `normal` isn't a property value for `display`. So please visit the [W3C website][1] to find the valid values.


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the hide the div when clicking any where on page except the selecteddiv

```
$(document).not("#selecteddiv").click(function() {
        $('#selecteddiv').hide();
    });
```

if you want to hide the div with lost focus or blur with animation then also

```
$("#selecteddiv").focusout(function() {
        $('#selecteddiv').hide();
    });
```

with animation

```
$("#selecteddiv").focusout(function() {
    $('#selecteddiv').animate({
        display:"none"
    });
});
```

May this will help you

Comment: somehow attaching it on 'body' and not 'document' work for me. I suppose document is object

Answer (score 5):

The examples already given unfortunately do not work if you have an iframe on your site and then click inside the iframe. Attaching the event to the document will only attach it to same document that your element is in.

You could also attach it to any iframes you're using, but most browsers won't let you do this if the iframe has loaded content from another domain.

The best way to do this is to copy what's done in the jQuery UI menubar plugin.

**Basic example HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">Click here to show the menu
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**And the jQuery needed to make it work:**

```
var timeKeeper;

$('#menu').click(function()
{
    $('#menu ul').show();
});

$('#menu ul').click(function()
{
    clearTimeout(timeKeeper);                  
});

$('#menu').focusout(function()
{
    timeKeeper = setTimeout(function() {$('#menu ul').hide()}, 150);
});

$('#menu').attr('tabIndex', -1);
$('#menu ul').hide();
```

What it does is give the menu a tab index, so that it can be considered to have focus. Now that you've done that you can use the focusout event handler on the menu. This will fire whenever it has been considered to lose focus. Unfortunately, clicking some child elements will trigger the focusout event (example clicking links) so we need to disable hiding the menu if any child elements have been clicked.

Because the focusout event gets called before the click event of any children, the way to achieve this is by setting a small timeout before hiding the element, and then a click on any child elements should clear this timeout, meaning the menu doesn't get hidden.

Here is my [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEW2g/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

   if (!container.is(e.target)&& container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
   {
      container.hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: I get container is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding mouse clicks, see the other answers.

However regarding lost focus, `.focusout` is not the event to attach to, but rather `.focusin`. Why? Consider the following popup:

```
<div class="popup">
  <input type="text" name="t1">
  <input type="text" name="t2">
</div>
```

What happens on moving from t1 to t2:

- t1 sends `focusout`, which bubbles up to `$('.popup').focusout`
- t2 sends `focusin`, which bubbles up to `$('.popup').focusin`

... so you get both types of event even though the focus stayed completely inside the popup.

The solution is to analogous to the magic trick done with `.click`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html').focusin(function() {
        $('.popup').hide(); 
    });
    $('.popup').focusin(function(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation(); 
    });
});
```

(side note: I found the `.not(...)` solution not working bc. of event bubbling).

Bonus: working fiddle [click me](http://jsfiddle.net/S437C/) - open the popup, then try tabbing through the inputs.

Comment: .focusin rather than .focusout?? Wow! So counter-intuitive, and yet it works both simply and beautifully. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a function on click of body and check if its the current div using e.target (e is the event)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").click(function(e) {     
    if($(e.target).attr('id') === "div-id") {
        $("#div-id").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#div-id").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work. where do i place this function? just inside a script tag?

Comment: it should be written after the body is loaded.. have edited my answer.

Comment: @naiquevin It shouldn't matter where he puts it, because it's wrapped inside a `$(document).ready` call

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this and here I found the solution https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/. This may be useful for future readers.

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant.

Answer (score 1):

On triggering mouseup() event, we can check the click is inside the div or a descendant and take action accordingly.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var divContent= $(".className");
    if(!divContent.is(e.target) && divContent.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $(".className").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't tried blur on divs, only on inputs etc. If blur eventhandler works, it's perfect and use it. If it doesn't, you could check this out:
[jQuery animate when <div> loses focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430277/jquery-animate-when-div-loses-focus)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu > li').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown('fast',function()
    {
        $(document).one('click',function()
        {
            $('.menu > li').children('ul').stop().slideUp('fast');
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think this will solve the OP's question?

Answer (score -1):

Showing is easy

```
$('somewhere').click(function {$('#foo').show();})
```

For hiding

[How do I hide a div when it loses its focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165411/how-do-i-hide-a-div-when-it-loses-its-focus/5165433#5165433)

Answer (score -2):

With jQuery you can hide elements with `hide()`, ex: `$("#foo").hide()`

Hide element in event listener:

```
$("#foo").blur(function() {
    $("#foo").hide();
});
```

Comment: there is no blur functio for div