# After clicking anywhere close menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, drop-down-menu

this is the jQuery I use for my mobile navigation, what I am trying to do is make the menu close again after clicking anywhere. So that when I visit a intern link it does not stay open. Can anyone please help me? Thanks for your time.

```
(function ($) {
  var $mobileNavToggleBtn = $('.mobile-nav-toggle');

  function onBtnClick (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $selectors = $('.mobile-nav');

    $this.toggleClass('is-open');
    $selectors.toggleClass('is-open');
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $mobileNavToggleBtn.on('click', onBtnClick);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you should watch for blur event. when the div loses focus you should toggle `is-open` class.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am new to this what do you mean? How should I do that?

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337828/hide-a-div-when-it-loses-focus-blur

Comment: I am a pain I know but your link does not Work.

Comment: Nvm I got it, Will try it now.

Comment: So if I get it right by adding the following, it should work right? But it does not.   $(document).not(".mobile-nav").click(function() {
        $('.mobile-nav').hide();
    });