# How to show hidden div onclick of button and hide when not in focus using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create add a way to show a div onclick of a button and hide it when not in focus / when user clicks outside the div.

I've already managed to add a button that can show a hidden div, but I can't figure out how to make it hidden again when focus is lost.

I've read this: [Hide a DIV when it loses focus/blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337828/hide-a-div-when-it-loses-focus-blur)

...and other articles, but I couldn't follow them to make it work..

Please see my code so far:

```js
function openCardsList() {
  let window = document.getElementById("anchor-cards-list");
  window.style.display = "block";
}
$(document).not("#anchor-cards-list").click(function() {
  $('#anchor-cards-list').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="collapse" id="anchor-cards-list">Lorem Ipsum</div>

<button id="anchor-open-cards-list-btn" onclick="openCardsList();">Collapse Maincard</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your snippet is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure about that error message, but it's working for me if I click the button, it shows the hidden div?

Comment: you should try blur function event for out of focus

Comment: @ruleboy21 it shows error because author's snippet including jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
function openCardsList() {
    let window = document.getElementById("anchor-cards-list");
    window.style.display = "block";
  }
  function hideDiv(){
    let window = document.getElementById("anchor-cards-list");
    window.style.display = "none";
  }
```

and add onclick event to parent div

```
div onclick="hideDiv()" style="height: 100vh;">
  <div class="collapse" id="anchor-cards-list">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution.. only problem I see is it closes the `div` even when clicking inside of it..

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally simplify things to separate concerns. Add an event listener to the button (click) to show your div, and an event listener (blur) on the div to hide it again.

```
document.getElementById('anchor-open-cards-list-btn').addEventListener('click', showDiv);
document.getElementById('anchor-cards-list').addEventListener('blur', hideDiv);
```

Then showDiv and hideDiv just handle the element visibility.

Answer (score 2):

i prefer to make let window outside the function so you can use it anytime needed. and also if you only make this for handle show/hide div while onclick and onblur you dont need jquery. the default javascript can deliver those event action.

script.js

```
let card = document.getElementById('anchor-cards-list')

function openCard() {
  card.style.display = 'block'
}

function blurCard() { 
 card.style.display = 'none'
}
```

index.html

```
<div id="anchor-cards-list">Hello Text</div>
<button onclick="openCard()" onblur="blurCard()">Clik me</button>
```

Comment: It would be a good practice to try to avoid using 'window' as a variable name , since window is already defined by default in the global scope

Comment: @Vibhu thanks for the correction, on my chrome it give a warning on console but since it work i ignored it

Answer (score 2):

**Use jquery simple way**

use toggle() instead of show/hide, because it is more clear and simple.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#anchor-open-cards-list-btn").click(function(){
   $("#anchor-cards-list").toggle();
 });
});
```

OR

```
function openCardsList() {
  $("#anchor-cards-list").toggle();
}
```

OR

For onblue you can also use this code

```
function openCardsList() {
 $("#anchor-cards-list").css('display','block');
}
function hideD(){
 $("#anchor-cards-list").css('display','none');
}
```

add onclick event in parent div

```
div onclick="hideD()">
 <div id="anchor-cards-list">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. however is this only to show/hide a div but not hide onblur?

Comment: for onblur the third one steps,
The first and second options are for show/hide div on single button

Answer (score -1):

const phoneCross=document.getElementById('phone-cross').addEventListener('click',function(){

```
            console.log('clicked phone cross button');
            // cross button display none successful way
            document.getElementById('main-phone-div').style.display='none';
```