# Make a jQuery element slide up if clicked anywhere outside of it

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down that I want to slideup when clicked anywhere outside of it (and all it's child elements)

My code seems to not be working :(

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('*').not(".drop").click(function() {
    $('.drop').slideUp('medium', function() {
// Animation complete.
});});});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hide element when clicked anywhere on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714471/jquery-hide-element-when-clicked-anywhere-on-the-page)

Comment: With the due respect. You have 6 unaccepted answers, I have 100% accepted answers. Your acceptance seems to not be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I hope this will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.drop').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('html').click(function() {
    var $drop = $('.drop');
    if($drop.is(":visible")) {
      $drop.slideUp('medium', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: A bad solution though as it doesn't make sense to always activate slideUp() when you are not even checking whether or not it might be hidden already.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.drop').is(':visible'))
        $('.drop').slideUp();
});

$(".drop").click(function() {
    $('.drop').slideDown();
    return false;
});
```