# Dropdown Menu Toggle Close

Tags: jquery

I have a simple dropdown menu that works nicely but is there a way so that if you click anywhere but the ul it will toggle it closed again?

Jquery

```
$('.header').click(function() {
    $('.menu').toggle();
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="header" href="#">All</a>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>All</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: anywhere as in anywhere in the body?

Comment: I think Jeremey's response here might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714471/jquery-hide-element-when-clicked-anywhere-on-the-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding:

```
$('.header').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.menu').toggle();
});
$('body').click(function() {
  $('.menu').hide();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tWDJD/18/)**.

Comment: This prevents it from being able to open again.

Comment: @GibsonFX Wow old answer but it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I would change toggle to toggleClass and add an active or open class in your css. You can also use an animation if you're using the JQuery UI. e.g.

```
.menu {
display:none;
}

.menu.active {
display:block;
}
```

then

```
$('.header').click(function(e) {
  $('.menu').toggleClass("active", 1000);
  if (!$('body').hasClass("menu-active")) {
    $('body').addClass("menu-active");
  }
});

$('body.menu-active').click(function(e) {
  $('.menu').removeClass("active");
  $('body').removeClass("menu-active");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as header exists inside the body the second line is cancelling out the first

Comment: @GibsonFX Good eye on an 8 year old question. Posted an edit with a fix. Thanks!

Comment: FYI You're missing a closing ) on line 3

Comment: @GibsonFX good eye again! I didn't test it but it looks right to me. Havn't touched jQuery in years.