# Hide div id when click out of it?

Tags: html, css

I making auto suggestion box.Autosugestions are displayed in div.I want to hide div id when click outside div id anywhere on page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714471/jquery-hide-element-when-clicked-anywhere-on-the-page

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use javascript for this. JQuery can help you here. Check if this is useful to you: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).click(function (event) {     
    $("#divid").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/)** may help you.