# jQuery: Can't hide element automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

I made a multiple selector with `multiple select` form element and a `text input`. I used jQuery `toggle()` method to **hide** and **show** multiple select item on click to the text input.  After showing the multiple selector, visitor can select multiple item with **ctrl** / **cmd** / **shift** key and then i need to hide the multiple select item. I can hide by clicking again to text input.

But i want it to hide automatically when im not working with multiple select item. Im using it twice in same page and using bootstrap. Now i could not find the way to solve it.

here is the source: http://jsfiddle.net/3UE7D/3/

Please help me.

Comment: `toggle()` used that way is deprecated, and you should probably be using `focus` and `blur` for this anyway, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3UE7D/4/) ?

Comment: i have tried with `focus` and `blur` before and with that result i can not select multiple data from multiple select item. thanks

Comment: Then you need to be more inventive, and do something like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/3UE7D/5/) ?

Comment: thanks. i have thought about `setTimeout`, but user might took more time to choice multiple item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714608/459974) would solve your problem

I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3UE7D/6/)

I added the following code there

```
$(document).click(function(){  
    $('select[name="location"]').slideUp(300);
});

$('select[name="location"]')
    .click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })    
    .hide();
```

Comment: thanks for your idea. i got the clear concept of e.stopPropagation() from http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ :)

Comment: Good stuff... sorry for the lack of explanation there about the e.stopPropagation()