# show and hide content by clicking button or background

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I tried to make a content, that gets viewed if you click a button an hides if you click that button again but also hides if you click anywhere else on the side except the content itself. 
Like on [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) if you click on tutorials. 
my attempt was this:

`$(":not(#content)").click` does not work. But even if, it would also get triggered all the times the content is not visible anyways. No good code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#content").toggle();

  });
  $(":not(#content)").click(function() {
    $("#content").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">This is the Content</div>

<button>switch</button>

<div> This is somewhere else </div>
```

Comment: This question similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714471/how-do-i-hide-an-element-on-a-click-event-anywhere-outside-of-the-element @Nils

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a click event listener to the document that hides the content if the clicked element was not the button or contained inside the content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#content").toggle();
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).closest('button, #content').length){
      $('#content').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" style="display: none;">This is the Content</div>
<button>switch</button>
<div> This is somewhere else </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content is not showing anymore because both events are fired when you click on "switch". If you need to prevent another external click event, use `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.cancelBubble = true`.

Comment these both lines and you will see the difference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(event){
    console.log("click button");
     event.stopPropagation();
     event.cancelBubble=true; 
    $("#content").toggle();
    
  });
  $("body").click(function(){
    console.log("click outside");
    $("#content").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">This is the Content</div>

<button>switch</button>

<div> This is somewhere else </div>
```

Comment: $event.stopPropagation(); if the "$" is in front it also works for buttons that are created during the runtime.

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.sorting', function(){  
  //$(".sorting").on('click', function(){    
  //$("button").click(function(){
   alert("clicked the button");
    $(this).after('<button class="sorting">new button</button>');
 $event.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  //$(document).on('click', document, function(){
  $(document).click(function() {
    alert("document was clicked");
  });
  
});